# Getting Error when testing Distance Censor with RaspberryPi3? Any suggetions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Below is my code, I often get "NameError: name 'start' is not defined"

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(0)
tr = 4
ec = 18
GPIO.setup(tr, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ec, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.output(tr, True)
time.sleep(0.0001)
GPIO.output(tr, False)

while GPIO.input(ec) == 0:
    start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(ec) == 1:
    end = time.time()

distance = (end-start) * 17200
print('Distance: {} cm'.format(distance))
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Can anyone have better code for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `start` in a while loop, if `GPIO.input(ec) != 0` when executed, `start` won't be defined and you'll get that error.

Put `start = 0` or `start = time.time()` before your `while` loops to be sure it is defined.

Same goes for the `end` variable